# Recomendation of Complex variables book

Tags: cv.complex-variables, textbook-recommendation

I'd like to ask for a book of complex variables that includes a "large" discussion about the Dirichlet problem, Neumann problem, and problems like that, I have now read "basic complex analysis - Marsden", but I want to read more about.

Answer (score 5):

Such a book is M. Lavrentiev and B. Shabat, Methods of the theory of functions of a complex
variable, it contains many applications, especially to various boundary value problems.
The book exists in Russian and Spanish. There is nothing similar in English, but look at
Henrici, Applied and computational complex analysis.